# Merging three lists together

Tags: python, merge

For fun, I am trying to implement k way merge sort where k =3. I do not have trouble with calling mergesort recursively but I am trying to merge three lists together but I am not getting a sorted list. The basic idea is that I compare the first element of every list and if it is the smallest I append it to a list. I repeat the process for all the arrays.

```
def three_merge(a,b,c):
    i =0
    j =0
    k=0
    list = []
    while(i < len(a) or j < len(b) or k < len(c)):
        while(a[i] <= b[j] and a[i] <= c[k]):
            list.append(a[i])
            i=i+1
            print i
        while(b[j] <= a[i] and b[j] <= c[k]):
            list.append(b[j])
            j=j+1
            print j
        while(c[k] <= a[i] and c[k] <= b[j]):
            list.append(c[k])
            k=k+1
            print k
   return list    

a = [1,2]
b = [-5,10]
c = [-11, 100]
print three_merge(a,b,c)
```

Comment: You know, there is probably a one/two-liner for this. `sort(a + b + c)` comes to mind.

Comment: Is `return list` supposed to be in your while loop or after it?

Comment: I'm trying to not use the built in function

Comment: why? is this homework or something or are you just trying to make this difficult? merge an array like python prefers you did; `list1 + list2`

Comment: @Alex good point...it's supposed to be after

Comment: I get a list index out of range error when I run this and I am not sure why

Comment: @phil12: because your inner `while` loops are not subject to the same constraints as your outer `while` loop is. Add `and (i < len(a) or j < len(b) or k < len(c) )` to them to fix that issue

Comment: are all three lists sorted prior to merge

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific about what is happening, instead of just saying you're not getting a sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you advance the indices `i, j, k` for each value you append to the sorted list, which means that the index is one greater than the length of the corresponding input list after taking all elements from the list. So when you compare the values of the elements for the different input lists, you eventually hit a point where you are trying to do, in effect, `a[len(a)]`, while will always give an index error.

Comment: It would be tedious to make changes to my existing code. I would probably have rewrite from scratch since with this code, I would have a bunch of if statements.

Comment: @phil12 Yes, so? Your current design doesn't work, so changes are needed. If it gets ugly, maybe a different approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function for n-way merge. Feel free to ask if you have questions:

```
def merge(*args):
    lst = list(args)
    idx = [0] * len(lst)
    out = []

    while lst:
        m = 0
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[i][idx[i]] < lst[m][idx[m]]:
                m = i
        out.append(lst[m][idx[m]])
        idx[m] += 1
        if idx[m] >= len(lst[m]):
            del lst[m]
            del idx[m]

    return out


print merge([1,2,11], [2,9], [8]) # [1, 2, 2, 8, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you consider a merge of three lists as a composition of two merges of two lists

```
def merge(a,b):
    L = a
    l = b
    i = 0
    j = 0
    res = []
    if (len(b)>len(a)):
        L=b
        l=a
    #print L
    #print l
    while (i<len(L)):
        if(len(l)>0):
            while (j<len(l)):
                if (L[i]<=l[j]):
                    res.append(L[i])
                    del L[i]
                    break
                else:
                    res.append(l[j])
                    del l[j]
        else:
            #print res
            res = list(res+L)
            L=[]
            break
    if len(l)>0:
        res = list(res+l)
        l=[]
    return res

def threeMerge(a,b,c):
    return merge(merge(a,b),c)

aa = [1,2]
bb = [-5,3,20]
cc= [-11, 23,45]
print threeMerge(aa,bb,cc)
```